# Abstract calculus book

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

Usually a calculus or real analysis book has the following topics

1. Convergence of sequences and functions
2. Continuity
3. Differentiability
4. Integrability

I am searching a book with those topics but such that each topic is developed in the most abstract way, i.e. convergence and continuity maybe from the perspective of topology or metric spaces and integrability from Lebesgue perspective. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Carothers' Real Analysis may be just below what you want.

Comment: Why?  What is your long term goal?  Typically, ideas are not developed abstractly---they are developed in very concrete settings, and then you start looking for the useful generalization.  Moreover, it generally takes more work to develop the abstract ideas, which is why they are generally developed in different texts (e.g. a topological treatment of analysis will generally be done in a topology text, not an analysis text).  No matter what the category theorists say, no one actually *learns* mathematics from the the most abstract point of view first.

Comment: Differential Calculus on Normed Spaces: A Course in Analysis by Cartan most certainly does what you want for $1,2$ and $3$. I don't recall whether he uses the Lebesgue integral, but he does everything in Banach spaces.

Comment: Rudin's books fit this fairly well, I think. [Analysis Now](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Now-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387967885) by Pedersen is also worth a look.

Comment: I used to believe that teaching calculus in Banach spaces for first year students is a great idea until I was TA for such a class. The average student does not deal well with that setting. There are plenty of technical difficulties that obscure what is really going on (e.g. linear maps need no longer be continuous) and quite often one would like to say that this is the same as for euclidean space, but students have not seen it. I guess what I want to say is that if it works for you, then that is great, but there is no need to force yourself :) In any case, enjoy the journey!

Comment: @XanderHenderson While I share your overall sentiment, I think we should let people try to find their own way. For some people it works to learn these things directly in a more abstract setting. Clearly there are some limits (I mean, I would not have recommended something with convenient vector spaces or the likes of it), but I feel it is important to students to figure what works for them. My first semester linear algebra class was mostly about endomorphisms of finitely generated modules over commutative rings and it did not hurt me (though I probably would not teach it that way).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The point is that no one really learns this way, hence no one really *writes* this way, either.  There are texts which are written from a more abstract point of view, but they typically depend on the reader *already* knowing the more concrete point of view.  Which is why my original (and most important question) was "**Why?**", followed by "What is your long term goal?"

Comment: @XanderHenderson As said before, I agree that the majority does not learn this way, but there are people that do (that is why I'd never structure a class like that), but if you have somebody that wants to self-study the more abstract version on the side, then I am more than willing to recommend some book. But presumably that is what want to hear with you "why?". I just don't feel we should shoot down somebody that is intrinsically motivated to learn some math, just caution them that it might not be for them and that it would be ok if it wasn't.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I don't think that I have shot down *anyone*.  Rather, I have asked for clarification, and also noted that such a book likely doesn't really exist, because that isn't the way that people think about things.  At this point, it is up to the author of the question to explain what they *actually* want, and why.

Comment: "A Course in Analysis, Volume II", by Elon Lages Lima is an excellent and very complete book which has all of those topics.

Answer (score 1):

Do you read French or, say, Russian? Analysis (Cours d'analyse) by Laurent Schwartz is pretty close to your request. But I do not think it was translated into English.

Another book you may try is the recent book by Barry Simon "Real Analysis: A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 1" ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470410990))

The major difference is that the latter book does assume a good background (it is listed in introduction), whereas the former starts from scratch and self contained (personal remark: I would kill myself if it was my first book in analysis).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your purpose is, but you could perhaps have a look at [Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0126227608) by Eric Schechter.

(See also the [description on the author's own web page](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/ccc/index.html).)

Answer (score 1):

See what you think of Gleason, Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis, https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/fundamentals-of-abstract-analysis

There's also Loomis and Sternberg, Advanced Calculus, https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/fundamentals-of-abstract-analysis
Table of contents:
Introduction
Vector Spaces
Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces
The Differential Calculus
Compactness and Completeness
Scalar Product Spaces
Differential Equations
Multilinear Functionals
Integration
Differentiable Manifolds
The Integral Calculus on Manifolds
Exterior Calculus
Potential Theory in $E^n$
Classical Mechanics